# A question on characteristic functions

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I am trying to understand a proof of the following:

Let $X_1,...,X_n$ be stochastic variables in $\mathbb{R}^n$. Then the following statements are equivalent:

i) $X_1,...,X_n$ are independent.

ii) $\mu_X=\mu_{X_1}\otimes ...\otimes \mu_{X_n}$.

iii) $E(\prod_{k}f_k(X_k))=\prod_kE(f_k(X_k))$ for all bounded Borel functions $f_1,...,f_n$

iv) $\phi_X(u)=\prod_k\phi_{X_k}(u_k)$ for all $u=(u_1,...,u_n)$.

Now, the only thing about the proof I can't understand, is the step (iv)$\Rightarrow$(i). Now, the professor said that we assume (iv) and choose independent stochastic variables $\bar{X}_1,..., \bar{X}_n$ with $\mu_{\bar{X}_k}=\mu_{X_k}$ for all $k$. Then we know that (i)$\Rightarrow$(iv), so

$\phi_{\bar{X}}(u)=\prod_k\phi_{\bar{X}_k}(u_k)\stackrel{?}{=}\prod_k\phi_{X_k}(u_k)=\phi_X(u)$,

so $\mu_{\bar{X}}=\mu_X$ by uniqueness of characteristic functions. Then we get (i).

I've marked out the step that I don't understand. Why does this hold? Is it because of the uniqueness as well?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is because the characteristic function is completely determined by the distribution. In other words, if two random variables $X$ and $Y$ have the same distribution ($\mu_X=\mu_Y$ in your notation), then obviously
$$
\varphi_X(u)={\rm E}[e^{iuX}]={\rm E}[e^{iuY}]=\varphi_Y(u),\quad u\in\mathbb{R}.
$$

Answer (score 0):

Even if $\bar{X}_k$ and $X_k$ are defined on different probability spaces, they have the same law i.e. $\mu_{\bar{X}_k}(B) = \mu_{X_k}(B)$ for all $B \in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$ (assuming the random variables are real valued) and therefore
\begin{equation}
 \int e^{i u_k x}\, \mu_{\bar{X}_k}(dx) = \int e^{i u_k x}\, \mu_{X_k}(dx).
\end{equation}